# Determine if View is being rendered as Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Is there a way to determine if a view is rendering as a partial?

I'm hoping to extend the reuse of a partial that I'm writing by catching this...and if necessary assigning the appropriate layout to the View.

At the moment I'm just rendering it in a div, but I could also see us using it as a modal and possible it's own page.

(the modal shouldn't require any change so no worries there)

EDIT: 
To clear up what I'm asking.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to determine the difference between a view being rendered by...

`/path/to/controller`

and

`Html.Partial("/path/to/view.cshtml")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Pheonixblade9 's response and the lack of other answers it doesn't appear like this is possible at the moment.  I ended up just binding the `Model` of the View as `bool` and pass this value in when rendering the view/partial.

Answer (score 7):

Why not @if (Layout==null)?
Still I would recommend another view for the "own" page and set the layout there.

Answer (score 1):

In your view (assuming Razor syntax):

```
@if(typeof(this) == Controller.PartialView)) //code
```

or

```
@if(this is Controller.PartialView) //code
```

Comment: I am using Razor.  So just to confirm if went to the path of that view directly this will return `false`, but if I do `Html.Partial()` it will be `true`?

Comment: This is just a basic answer, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  You'll need to include some sort of flag if you want the rendered page to have a way of indicating whether or not it's rendered as a PartialView from the Views folder

Comment: I've added some info to the question for clarification.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't believe there is a way to tell this without including some sort of attribute to pass client side.  The response is just giving you HTML, it doesn't include any information about how it is generated.

Comment: Good enough.  At the moment there isn't any model binding happening so I may just bind it to bool since there isn't a way to do this through the framework.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution.  You might yet get an answer that I'm not aware of! :)